# When to use Guava sameThreadExecutor

Tags: guava

I just ran into a code like this:

```
ExecutorService executorService = MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  executorService.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
      try {
        Do some work here...
        return null;
      } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw e;
      } finally {
        //
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Any difference between this and the code snippet below? If I understand it correctly, sameThreadExecutor uses the same thread that calls submit(), which means all these 10 "jobs" are run one by one on the main thread.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      try {
        Do some work here...
      } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw e;
      } finally {
        //
      }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Its the same. A common use-case is unit testing classes where you don't want the complexity to handling asynchronous executions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, [`MoreExecutors#sameThreadExecutor`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#sameThreadExecutor()) is deprecated:

> **Deprecated.** Use `directExecutor()` if you only require an `Executor` and `newDirectExecutorService()` if you need a `ListeningExecutorService`. **This method will be removed in August 2016.**

So question is: when do you need [`MoreExecutors#directExecutor`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#directExecutor()) or [`MoreExecutors#newDirectExecutorService`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#newDirectExecutorService()) (difference between those two is mentioned above - `ListeningExecutorService` is Guava's extension for `ListenableFuture`s). Answers are:

- use it when you need `Executor` / `ExecutorService` (ex. your interface requires it) and don't want concurrency but rather run your multi-threaded code synchronously
- (implied by above) use it in tests for predictable results
- when you'd want to implement simple `ExecutorService` like `newDirectExecutorService` by yourself, but don't want to reinvent the wheel (see [its source code](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#line.286))
- if you're using [`ListenableFuture##addCallback(ListenableFuture, FutureCallback)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#addCallback(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture,%20com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback)), `newDirectExecutorService` is used by default (["for use when the callback is fast and lightweight"](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained#adding-callbacks), also mentions it's "a dangerous choice in some cases" (see [javadoc](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#addCallback(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture,%20com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback)))).